# Passing the value of a td cell thru onclick Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a single column html table with 20 rows, containing strings (used as tags):

```
<table id="table_of_tags">
  <tr>
    <td id="c_01" onclick="Pass_Content_Of_Cell(_param)">Tree</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c_02" onclick="Pass_Content_Of_Cell(_param)">Flower</td>
    </tr>
  ....
  </table>
```

The function Pass_Content_of_Cell() must pass the contents of the cells clicked and concatenate the tags in a single string of tags: "Flower;Tree;" (WHAT it does is not relevant).

The user can click randomly on any tag and in any order he likes.

Question: What exactly should I use for **_param** ? I tried **this.value** and **this.text** and didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
onclick="Pass_Content_Of_Cell(this.innerText)"
```

or if you want the markup,

```
onclick="Pass_Content_Of_Cell(this.innerHTML)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.innerText

```
<table id="table_of_tags">
<tr><td id="c_01" onclick="Pass_Content_Of_Cell(this.innerText)">Tree</td><tr>
<tr><td id="c_02" onclick="Pass_Content_Of_Cell(this.innerText)">Flower</td><tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you all (Nico - yours is not an answer to my question). It seems I was digging in the right direction, but not yet there - and who knows when I would have found the answer ? I scoured the www for half an hour or so before I decided to ask my (simpleton) question here. I see that I can use any of your answers. Obviously, I am a beginner at JavaScript. Rem: In Pascal (my 1st progr language) this would not have been possible - 4 ways to do the same thing. And that's how things should be.

Comment: The ids of the table cells (c_01, c_02 etc.) are actually not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a loop to generate the markup, why you simply didn't do something like:

```
<tr><td onClick="doSomething('$param')">$param</td></tr>
```

I cannot imagine the list is hardcoded...

Comment: The tags are not related. I would have to construct an array of tags, or read them from a file/table. There is not a big difference. The hard part was to DEFINE the tags - and they are not Tree or Flower. This is an example, to make the question easier to understand.

Comment: It DOESN'T, does it ? Nevertheless, you didn't answer my question. Maybe some other time...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function save(val1)
{
alert("you have saved Employee "+document.getElementById(val1).innerText);  
}
function del(val1)
{
    alert("you have deleted Employee "+document.getElementById(val1).innerText);    
}
</script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>EmployeeID</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Option</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1590</td>
    <td id="c1">Venkatesh</td> 
    <td>venki@w3s.com</td>
    <td>9943243433</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="dlt1" name="dlt1" onclick="del('c1');"><input type="button" value="Save" id="sv1" name="sv1" onclick="save('c1');"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>1591</td>
    <td id="c2">amarnath</td> 
    <td>amar@w3s.com</td>
    <td>9943113433</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="dlt1" name="dlt1" onclick="del('c2');"><input type="button" value="Save" id="sv1" name="sv1" onclick="save('c2');"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>1601</td>
    <td id="c3">naveen</td> 
    <td>navs@w3s.com</td>
    <td>9943113433</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Delete" id="dlt1" name="dlt1" onclick="del('c3');"><input type="button" value="Save" id="sv1" name="sv1" onclick="save('c3');"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is a sample html code with javascript function hope this help guys